# How to make semantic-ui sidebar not dim page content when triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

How to make the pusher not dim when I trigger the semantic-ui sidebar?

I tried the semantic-ui sidebar as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $('.button').click(
      function() {
        $('.ui.sidebar')
          .sidebar('toggle');
      }
    )
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>

<button class="ui button">trigger</button>
<div class="ui right demo sidebar vertical inverted menu push visible" style="">
  <a class="header item">File Permissions</a>
  <a class="item">Share on Social</a>
  <a class="item">Share by E-mail</a>
  <a class="item">Edit Permissions</a>
  <a class="item">Delete Permanently</a>
</div>
```

The pusher content should not be dimmed when sidebar is triggered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can control the dimmer behavior of the sidebar with the `dimPage` setting. You can prevent dimming as follows:

```
$('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('setting', 'dimPage', false);
```

Here is an example snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('setting', 'dimPage', false);
  $('#hamburger').click(() => {
    $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui sidebar inverted vertical menu">
  <a class="item" href="#">Item 1</a>
  <a class="item" href="#">Item 2</a>
</div>
<div class="pusher">
  <div class="ui container">
    <button class="ui button" id="hamburger">
      <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
    </button>
    <p>Some content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```